# python os.rename directory not empty

Tags: python, python-os

I'm trying to do `mv test-dir/* ./` but in python. I have written the following code but throws `OSError: [Errno 66] Directory not empty:`

```
import os    
os.rename(
    os.getcwd() + '/test-dir',
    os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser('.')))
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use [shutil.move()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) to iteratively move the files from a directory to another.
For example,

```
import os
import shutil

from_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"test-dir")
to_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser('.'))

for file in os.listdir(from_dir):
    shutil.move(os.path.join(from_dir, file), to_dir)
```

Comment: Can I use `mv` through subprocess call? @abc

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the OS to move `test-dir`, not its contents. It would normally replace the target (`.` in this case) but that target obviously isn't empty, so the implicit `rmdir` fails. Even if it weren't empty, it's likely impossible to remove or replace the `.` name.

The shell `*` is a [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#module-glob), which would expand to each thing within `test-dir`, which you could move individually; however, you'd want to transfer their name to the target directory, i.e. `test-dir/foobar` to `./foobar`. [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) can help you extract that portion.